# Mandar al frente un formulario despues de N instancias

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy llevando a cabo un programa muy sencillo para guardar los seguimientos o llamadas que le hacemos a los clientes, esto en C#, originalmente agregue un código que encontré aquí mismo para verificar si el formulario ya esta abierto, si no lo esta crea la instancia o si existe lo trae al frente.

```
Form existe = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().Where(pre => pre.Name == "frmClientes").SingleOrDefault<Form>();
                      
            if (existe != null )
            {
                existe.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                existe.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                frmClientes frm = new frmClientes();
                frm.Show();
            }*/
```

Pero ahora tengo la necesidad de que se generen 2 instancias de algunos formularios, esto debido de que al momento de estar capturando cierta información en 1, se pueda guardar información de otro cliente de forma urgente(llamadas que entran), sin tener que cerrar la primer ventana, para posteriormente finalizar esa captura. He estado intentando lo siguiente, si bien me funciona pues solo me permite abrir la cantidad de formularios que deseo, pero al dar clic por tercera ves en el botón, en vez de generar una nueva instancia, deseo que mande al frente los formularios, pero es ahí donde tengo el problema, me parece que el código no llega a ejecutarse nunca, y no veo como hacerlo funcionar, intento poner un else pero no puedo acceder a la instancia, por ello intento con un if anidado.

```
private void btnNuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //CODIGO SOLO PERMITE 2 INSTANCIAS DEL FORMULARIO CLIENTES
            //---------------------------------------------
            int existe = Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmClientes>().Count();
            if (existe < 2)
            {
                frmClientes frm = new frmClientes();
                frm.Show();
                if (existe ==2)
                {
                    frm.BringToFront();
                    frm.Show();
                }

            }
```

Por lo que me dedici a preguntar en el sitio sobre ¿como mandar al frente un formulario despues de N cantidad de instancias?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `if` anidado no funciona porque si el valor es menor que dos `if (existe < 2)` nunca será igual a dos.

Por otra parte, necesitas tener acceso a las dos instancias ya creadas. Una forma de hacerlo es utilizando nuevamente [`Application.OpenForms.OfType<>()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_OfType__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) que devuelve un `IEnumerable` que contiene todas las instancias del tipo especificado (`frmClientes` en tu caso)

El código sería algo así:

```
private void btnNuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CODIGO SOLO PERMITE 2 INSTANCIAS DEL FORMULARIO CLIENTES
    //---------------------------------------------
    int existe = Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmClientes>().Count();
    if (existe < 2)
    {
        frmClientes frm = new frmClientes();
        frm.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmClientes>())
        {
            item.BringToFront();
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Funciono perfectamente!, no tenia idea de como acceder a las instancias ya creadas, tu aporte resolvio mi problema, gracias!.